# How to create friendly URL in php?

Tags: php, url, friendly-url

Normally, the practice or very old way of displaying some profile page is like this:

```
www.domain.com/profile.php?u=12345
```

where `u=12345` is the user id.

In recent years, I found some website with very nice urls like:

```
www.domain.com/profile/12345
```

How do I do this in PHP?

Just as a wild guess, is it something to do with the `.htaccess` file? Can you give me more tips or some sample code on how to write the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: See also this other StackOverflow question: [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 52):

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140220075845/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls), you want a mod_rewrite (placed in an `.htaccess` file) rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)\.html /news.php?news_id=$1
```

And this maps requests from

```
/news.php?news_id=63
```

to

```
/news/63.html
```

**Another possibility is doing it with `forcetype`**, which forces anything down a particular path to use php to eval the content. So, in your `.htaccess` file, put the following:

```
<Files news>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

And then the index.php can take action based on the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    // outputs '/63.html'
?>
```

Comment: A great mod_rewrite resource: http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Another option, if you want to do your URL rewriting entirely PHP, is to set rewrite rules to direct all requests to a single script.  One great advantage of this, is you can store your code in an area not accessible to Apache, and only your URL dispatching script need be Apache-accessible.  e.g.:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . dispatch.php

This is similar to your forcetype example.

Comment: Article on Phpriot was removed, [read it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080725204042/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls). It's very good piece.

Comment: if id=1 , and post_name="red post" , then is there any possibility to create url like example.com/red-post.php . Currently i am creating url like example.com/post/?id=1 . ie How to make slug(url) by post name

Comment: The links posted by `James Socol` and `Chad Birch` are broken.

Answer (score 32):

I recently used the following in an application that is working well for my needs.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
foreach (explode ("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) as $part)
{
    // Figure out what you want to do with the URL parts.
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I try to explain this problem step by step in following example.

**0) Question**

I try to ask you like this :

i want to open page like facebook profile www.facebook.com/kaila.piyush

it get id from url and parse it to profile.php file and return featch data from database and show user to his profile

normally when we develope any website its link look like
www.website.com/profile.php?id=username
example.com/weblog/index.php?y=2000&m=11&d=23&id=5678

now we update with new style not rewrite we use www.website.com/username or example.com/weblog/2000/11/23/5678 as permalink

```
http://example.com/profile/userid (get a profile by the ID) 
http://example.com/profile/username (get a profile by the username) 
http://example.com/myprofile (get the profile of the currently logged-in user)
```

**1) .htaccess**

Create a .htaccess file in the root folder or update the existing one :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

What does that do ?

If the request is for a real directory or file (one that exists on the server), index.php isn't served, else every url is redirected to index.php.

**2) index.php**

Now, we want to know what action to trigger, so we need to read the URL :

In index.php :

```
// index.php    

// This is necessary when index.php is not in the root folder, but in some subfolder...
// We compare $requestURL and $scriptName to remove the inappropriate values
$requestURI = explode(‘/’, $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]);
$scriptName = explode(‘/’,$_SERVER[‘SCRIPT_NAME’]);

for ($i= 0; $i < sizeof($scriptName); $i++)
{
    if ($requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i])
    {
        unset($requestURI[$i]);
    }
}

$command = array_values($requestURI);
With the url http://example.com/profile/19837, $command would contain :

$command = array(
    [0] => 'profile',
    [1] => 19837,
    [2] => ,
)
Now, we have to dispatch the URLs. We add this in the index.php :

// index.php

require_once("profile.php"); // We need this file
switch($command[0])
{
    case ‘profile’ :
        // We run the profile function from the profile.php file.
        profile($command([1]);
        break;
    case ‘myprofile’ :
        // We run the myProfile function from the profile.php file.
        myProfile();
        break;
    default:
        // Wrong page ! You could also redirect to your custom 404 page.
        echo "404 Error : wrong page.";
        break;
}
```

**2) profile.php**

Now in the profile.php file, we should have something like this :

```
// profile.php

function profile($chars)
{
    // We check if $chars is an Integer (ie. an ID) or a String (ie. a potential username)

    if (is_int($chars)) {
        $id = $chars;
        // Do the SQL to get the $user from his ID
        // ........
    } else {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($char);
        // Do the SQL to get the $user from his username
        // ...........
    }

    // Render your view with the $user variable
    // .........
}

function myProfile()
{
    // Get the currently logged-in user ID from the session :
    $id = ....

    // Run the above function :
    profile($id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed post, i always wanted to learn , how sites like wordpress generate pretty urls and can access them without editing htaccess file everytime, thanks

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: How do you handle #anchors?

Answer (score 10):

Simple way to do this. Try this code. Put code in your `htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule profile/(.*)/ profile.php?u=$1

RewriteRule profile/(.*) profile.php?u=$1
```

It will create this type pretty URL:

> http://www.domain.com/profile/12345/

For more htaccess Pretty URL:http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

Comment: Simple and elegant. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not PHP, it's apache using mod_rewrite. What happens is the person requests the link, www.example.com/profile/12345 and then apache chops it up using a rewrite rule making it look like this, www.example.com/profile.php?u=12345, to the server. You can find more here: [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score -1):

ModRewrite is not the only answer. You could also use Options +MultiViews in .htaccess and then check `$_SERVER REQUEST_URI` to find everything that is in URL.

Comment: Yeah, but MultiViews is icky... I'd say it's too general for this usage.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of different ways to do this. One way is to use the RewriteRule techniques mentioned earlier to mask query string values.

One of the ways I really like is if you use the [front controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) pattern, you can also use urls like http://yoursite.com/index.php/path/to/your/page/here and parse the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

You can easily extract the /path/to/your/page/here bit with the following bit of code:

```
$route = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

From there, you can parse it however you please, but for pete's sake make sure you sanitise it ;)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are talking about a RESTful webservice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

The .htaccess file does rewrite all URIs to point to one controller, but that is more detailed then you want to get at this point. You may want to look at [Recess](http://www.recessframework.org/)

It's a RESTful framework all in PHP

Comment: Technically I suppose you are right, but unless the OP is already experienced with the REST idea, even reading that Wikipedia article is far more effort than the problem needs. Invoking a whole programming paradigm is overkill for this situation.

Comment: Really? I don't think his questions was exactly "How do I make profile.php?u=12345 goto /profile/12345", I interpreted that as an overall "How is this done in production environments?". I think it is beneficial to know that there IS a paradigm out there, and not have a .htaccess file full of redirects when there is a proper way to address that problem.