# How was a URL like http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1807421/edit created in PHP?

Tags: php, url, path, filenames

When you edit a question on stackoverflow.com, you will be redirected to a URL like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1807421/edit

But usually, it should be

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1807491/edit.php

or

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/edit.php?id=1807491

How was

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1807421/edit
>   created?

I know that Stackoverflow.com was not created by using PHP, but I am wondering how to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: It's not done with the server-side language, it's normally done using some web-server config. To get help doing it with Apache, go take a look at http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite.

Comment: Been asked many times, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php for example

Comment: Go look at virtually *any* php framework - they all do url routing in one form or another

Answer (score 7):

With apache and PHP, you might perform one of your examples using a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule in your apache config as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/posts/(\d+)/edit /posts/edit.php?id=$1
```

This looks for URLs of the "clean" form, and then rewrites them so that they are internally redirected to a particular PHP script.

Quite often rules like this are used to route all requests into a common controller script, which might do something like instantiate a "PostsController" class and ask it to handle an edit request. This is a common feature of most PHP application frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

It's called routing. Take a look at [tutorials](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/) on the subject.

If you use a framework such as [cake php](http://cakephp.org/) it should be built in.

Answer (score 2):

As @mr-euro stated you can use mod_rewrite but front controller is a far better solution.
You force every request to index.php and you write your application controlling in index.php.

Comment: Well this a really a debate question but for me front controller is a far better solution cause it handles ajax, templating and page generation, simply I have a less code, unified structure and simple ajax integration.

Answer (score 2):

You use Apache's .htaccess/mod_rewrite, and optionally a PHP file, which is the approach I like to take myself.

For the .htaccess, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Then in your PHP file, you can do something like this:

The following should get everything after the first slash.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You can then use explode to turn it into an array.

```
$split = explode('/', $url);
```

Now you can use the array to determine what to load:

```
if ($split[1] == 'home')
{
// display homepage
}
```

The array is starting from 1 since 0 will usually be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed done by mod_rewrite, or with multiviews. But i prefer mod_rewrite.

First: you create a .htaccessfile with these contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([0-9])/(edit|delete)$ /index.php?page=posts&postId=$1&action=$2
```

Obvious, mod_rewrite must be enabled by your hostingprovider ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite this can be achieved very easily.

Comment: For an up-vote you might take the time to explain *how* this can be achieved very easily using `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

I am poor at this but i do know you can redirect urls using apache mod_rewrite and by touching config files. From what i remember htaccess can be used to [redirect](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess7.shtml). Then internally when the user hits 
`http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1807421/edit` it can use your page `http://stackoverflow.com/edit.php?p=1807421` instead or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use htaccess + write an URI parser class.