# Make filename including extension not show in the URL?

Tags: php, apache

I would like to have the filename including the extension not show in the URL when requesting it. And I am wondering is this possible with a PHP & Apache combination - and how can this be achieved?

For example, this:

www.domain.com/folder/filename.php

Should become, this:

www.domain.com/folder/

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following rule in an `.htaccess` file will work:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/$ folder/filename.php [L]
```

A more dynamic rule that will rewrite `folder/<filename>` to `folder/filename.php` would be:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*[^\.php])$ folder/$1\.php [L]
```

**Reference**

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[An In Depth Guide to mod_rewrite for Apache](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)