# Friendly subfolder link to page (wikipedia style)

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I am struggling to find this as I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for!

I've seen that some sites seem to use 'subfolders' as links to pages, e.g. wikipedia.

E.g. Let's say I had a record in a database with a unique title "My Shopping List". I want to be able to navigate to **www.mySite.com/my_shopping_list** and have it automatically 'forward' to a page showing the relevant record.

I am using IIS and wondering if there's a way I can do it with that, but I may be looking in the wrong place.

This is for a knowledgebase where I might write an article called "how to use a computer" and would like to be able to create a 'friendly' link for users (**http://www.mySite.com/how_to_use_a_computer** rather than **http://www.mySite.com/article.php?ID=123**. I will need to be able to create these 'links' dynamically using the title field.

Thank you

EDIT: I am using IIS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use URL Rewrite, the microsoft ressource for this technique is here: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

In the [iss forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1160436.aspx) the issue about url rewrite in iss < 7 is discussed with some suggestions on software to use.

I don't know which one is best, maybe there are others who know:

http://iirf.codeplex.com/

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

http://urlrewriter.net/

Comment: This looks great although it appears to only be available for IIS7 upwards

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you'll need to code URLConf using something like a htaccess file or the manager GUI. You can read [ISS docs on URL rewrite to learn how.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/), but as I understand, this is a module you'll have to download separately.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php) also shows how do do it without editing server configuration files or htaccess, but you'll be stuck with a `http://example.com/index.php/path/to/view` format (where `index.php` is a real script with the URLConf in it.)

Answer (score 0):

Well some time ago it was used to call 'Friendly URL' or 'FURL', now i see that it's ust Rewrite URL. Look for tutorials for beginners.