# Php query string url issue

Tags: php, html

I've a php page with following string.

```
http://mydomain.com/businesspage.php?profile=Khafihan
```

So I'm trying to convert this url to following style

```
http://mydomain.com/Khafihan
```

Is it possible with php and how ?

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Comment: Use `.htaccess`! Read more...

Comment: You need to rewrite urls, search for mod_rewrite

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php) question should be helpful

Comment: Look up url rewrites for your web server. If you're still having trouble, modify your question to ask how to do this rewrite for the web server you are using.

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski how can i do this with .htaccess ?

Comment: If you are using Apache (I think: yes), you can create in main folder of your project file `.htaccess` and put their my or @AmalMurali magic lines! And it's end!

Answer (score 2):

I think this `.htaccess` rule should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /businesspage.php?profile=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Add `RewriteEngine On`!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the following lines into your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /businesspage.php?profile=$1
```

Comment: I'm trying your code.

Comment: I just created a .htaccess file and put it to my root folder. But nothing happened.

Comment: why it's not working, can you please tell me ?

Comment: Do you turn on your `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: I think No. I just put your code to .htaccess file.

Comment: You have Apache on witch system? (mac/win/lin)

Comment: windows and now i'm working on localhost.