# How to Manipulate $_GET in URL using PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Maybe this is a silly question but I spend much time through google and this site to search and read about this topic but it doesn't help.

My concern is how can I or is it possible to manipulate $_GET in URL using PHP and .htaccess? Let say I want to change:

```
detail.php?pro=abcd into detail/abcd/
```

So, whenever user hover or click on a link, it will display `detail/abcd` instead of `detail.php?pro=abcd`. I find a piece of code below to get it done using htaccess but i don't get any php code.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
> RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1
> </IfModule>
> ```

I really appreciate any help and thanks a lot

Comment: _i don't get any with php code_? What PHP code are you trying to find? `header('location: ... ');`?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^detail/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ detail.php?pro=$1`? This is simply changing a very few things in your htaccess that you already have?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create friendly URL's.

This question has been asked many times before, see this answer for information on how to do this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/812578/1209020