# URL Rewriting of a query string in php

Tags: php

Please tell me how to convert this url 
http://www.example.com/category_listing.php?cat=Astrology&city=Jaipur
into
http://www.example.com/Jaipur/Astrology

Comment: See this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/category_listing.php?cat=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&city=([a-zA-Z0-9]+) http://www.example.com/$1/$2
```

Write this rewrite rule in your .htaccess file

Comment: thanx for the reply but its not working!