# Topic search in search engines

Tags: php

I am developing a website similar to a web forum. Users will post queries and others help them through their replies. In many websites like mine, the topic of the query will be included in the URL, e.g. `www.sample.com/topic-1.html` or `www.sample.com/topic-2.html`, and these links can be found via search engines.

How can I dynamically generate the HTML files and configure my website so that search engines can access it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0):

No, they usually aren't putting these files on web server manually. They are rewriting urls using web server (e.g. apache2/nginx). Check the response headers to get more info about what happens behind the scenes.

Please see [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)