# .htaccess Rewrite - PHP get variable to fake folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, I was wondering if I could take a url like:

> http://Localhost/Core/?page=signin

and rewrite it to

> http://Localhost/Core/signin/

like a "fake" folder.

I'm using CSRF and when I submit the form it doesn't like PHP get variables in the url. I was hoping that if I were to use a "fake" folder it would change and then work..? Maybe not, any thoughts?

Comment: Similar question to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Core/([^/]*)$ /Core/?page=$1 [L]
```

Using this your page variable can be access in your `php` file