# How to change the url variales in php?

Tags: php

How do i change the url http://localhost/Test/www/#/home/login.php?name=abc
to 
http://localhost/Test/www/#/home/login/abc

I need to access the name variable from url

I have tried to modify .htaccess but i am getting. Please some help me out.

Comment: Look at these ans;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html

Comment: what `#` for ? mosty rewriting do with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

For you to achieve that, you can do a mod_rewrite (placed in an `.htaccess` file) rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/login/([0-9]+)\.html /login.php?name=abc
```

And this maps requests from

```
/login.php?name=abc
```

to

```
/login/abc.html
```

Another possibility is doing it with `forcetype`, which forces anything down a particular path to use php to eval the content. So, in your .htaccess file, put the following:

```
<Files login>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

And then the `index.php` can take action based on the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    // outputs '/abc.html'
?>
```