# I want to manipulate the source url

Tags: php

If a user is in a page 
www.sitename.com/folder/index.php
and he clicks on a url to another page/site
but the second page should not detect that the user is coming from www.sitename.com/folder/index.php
instead it should show
www.sitename.com/someting/somethingelse

in short I want to manipulate the source url

is the htaccess rewrite  going to help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create friendly URL in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Comment: wrong duplicate @andrew

Comment: on click, redirect to your somethingelse page. Then, redirect to the target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

in your page:

```
<a class='redirectable' href='somewhere'>Link1</a>
<a class='redirectable' href='somewhere'>Link2</a>
<a href='somewhere'>Link3</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.redirectable').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = 'myRedirectPage.php?target=' + $(this).attr('href');
    });  
});
```

in myRedirectPage.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['target']))
  header('Location: '+trim($_GET['target']));
```

Comment: Its a redirection code, right ? but the problem is
www.sitename.com/someting/somethingelse
has content in it , and I cant redirect it.
I just mask to manipulate that the click is coming from that particular page...

Comment: you can put the code at the top of it. So, it redirects only when you are passing 'target' parameter. (or any parameter you want)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mojtaba.

From original page, you can link to www.sitename.com/someting/somethingelse, which automatically redirects to target page.

Comment: Its a redirection code, right ? but the problem is www.sitename.com/someting/somethingelse has content in it , and I cant redirect it. I just mask to manipulate that the click is coming from that particular page...