# Changing the URL pattern in PHP

Tags: php

Right now my URL looks like:
https://www.example.com/blogitem.php?id=29

What I want is the user will see the URL in their browser like:
https://www.example.com/blogitem/the-title-of-the-current-blog

This thing is already implemented in Wordpress and other CMS but I am using pure PHP and don't have any idea about how can I implement this feature. Can anyone please help me to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this on code .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogitem.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

you need to get title form database instead of id
so it will be like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogitem.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I added this code to .htaccess file but the URL patterns remains same...

Comment: if you have added this                                                                                                                  
        `RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogitem.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`                                         and try url on browser  https://www.example.com/29

Comment: This does the trick... if I want the URL like "https://www.example.com/blog/the-title-of-the-blog" then how can I configure the .htaccess file?

Comment: you have to select the-title-of-the-current-blog from the database instead of Id on your url . then you change this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogitem.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`    to this  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogitem.php?the-title-of-the-current-blog=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I fetched all the required titles from DB... currently it shows the URL like this: "https://www.example.com/title-of-the-blog" but I want like this: "https://www.example.com/blog/title-of-the-blog". Notice the "/blog/" in the middle of the URL

Comment: `blogitem.php?the-title-of-the-current-blog=/blog/$1 [L,QSA]`       OR create a folder name it blog and insert blogitem.php file in that folder.