# How do websites use dashes in the URL to get information rather than using PHP's $_GET?

Tags: javascript, php, html, social-networking

How is it websites use dashes like in this Reddit URL(https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/7onp85/what_can_you_add_to_mac_n_cheese_to_make_it_even/) rather than using $_GET statements in PHP(www.google.com?post=mac_n_cheese_to_make&vartwo=test)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with further examples? PHP is not the only server side language. Also - that example contains no dashes "-" but lots of underscores "_" that are simply placeholders for spaces in english.

Comment: FYI: it's the `7onp85` that tells the server what to load, the `what_can_you_add_to_mac_n_cheese_to_make_it_even/` bit can be altered without changing the content of the page. In this case the server will redirect to an unchanged version of the url.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can get the path used to access a resource with the **$_SERVER** global variable.

In your case :

**PHP File:** /r/AskReddit/comments/7onp85/what_can_you_add_to_mac_n_cheese_to_make_it_even/index.php

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

should return : 

`/r/AskReddit/comments/7onp85/what_can_you_add_to_mac_n_cheese_to_make_it_even/`

The only problem is that if the folders don't exist, or the file `index.php` doesn't exist in path `/r/AskReddit/comments/7onp85/what_can_you_add_to_mac_n_cheese_to_make_it_even/`
 you will end up with a 404 Not Found Error.

To remedy on this, you usually tell your WebServer (Apache, Nginx, etc.) that every request has to be processed by one single script, say `/index.php` on document root.

For Apache, this can be done with a simple `.htaccess` file in the root of the web server :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # if the request [-d]irectory !exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # or if the request [-f]ile !exists
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] # then execute /index.php
```

This basically tells apache to redirect every request with an invalid path to the */index.php* file in the root of you webserver. Instead of ending with a 404, the */index.php* script will be executed.

You can then parse the *$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']* variable and print different outputs depending on the path the script has been accessed with.

Comment: by far it is easyer to use a PHP router which support wildcard like fastroute :)

Comment: I think routers are easier to use when you understand the basics behind it. And you still need to rewrite nevertheless.