# How to make blog based website from scratch using php and mysql?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, url, blogs

I don't want to make a single page that will handle all the posts like the URL:

`somewebsite.com/blog.php?blog=2232`

I want that every blog should appear like:

`somewebsite.com/blog1/`

`somewebsite.com/blog2/`

For example, WordPress displays every post in its URL. I want the same functionality.

Comment: Possibly [URL rewriting with PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/16388959) + [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Comment: Your title and your question are not in agreement - they are asking for very different things.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is .htaccess's RewriteRule
What you want to add is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?blog=$1
```

When adding this, /blog/5 will display the content of blog.php?blog=5

Also, check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is pretty URLs/friendly URLs.

Here you can read more about it: [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php).

And also I found a tutorial about it [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049).

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: Yup, but I can't make comments yet :'c

Comment: ohh ok my bad, hope you will get privilege soon :)

Comment: Chezz: we ask on Stack Overflow that answers are more than links to elsewhere, mainly because links break over time. Also, if you know that a question is a duplicate (identified in the comments) then another answer is probably not necessary.