# htaccess file to use forward slash instead of ?, = and & signs in query string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I am creating a small e-commerce website. There we have a list of items which user can click and explore the information about the item. I am passing the item id and and some other information in the query string so on the next page I can get the related data from database.

Right now we have the following URL default structure:

```
www.somedomain.com/item.php?id=1&some1=somevalue&some2=somevalue
```

But I want the URL like:

```
www.somedomain.com/item/1/somevalue/somevalue
```

Where `item` is `item.php` and `/1/somevalue/somevalue` is query string `?id=1&some1=somevalue&some2=somevalue`. I want my whole website query string parameters like above.

I am using core PHP, no framework. I did some with `.htaccess` files but the server gives errors while loading the website. How can I do this with `.htaccess` file?

Comment: are you using a framework (or a front controller pattern)?

Comment: I am using core PHP, no framework.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below, I am using mod_rewrite to achieve the result, clear cache if using any previous attempts.

Below will also cover '_' underscore and next rule after will be for only one item.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php?id=$2&some1=$3&some2=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\_]+)/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?item=$2[L]
```

Comment: It is limited to the item page or whole domain?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I use your file and call the page with the query string that i want, it says not found.

Comment: you have to call this www.somedomain.com/item/1/somevalue/somevalue right?

Comment: Yes i did but not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205075/discussion-between-abhishek-gurjar-and-stack-overflow).