# htaccess redirect profile page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm creating a system which shows your profile if you visit http://example.com/profile/profile.php?username=test

I would like to make it so you could go to http://example.com/profile/test and it would still work.
At the same time I would like it to show ^^ as the url if you visit http://example.com/profile/profile.php?username=test

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ http://example.com/profile/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

You want to match everything after profile/ to the end of URI, and then pass it as parameter value to your "real" URI.

[L] flag may not be necessary, it indicates the rewrite engine you're done and it does not have to go throught the next rules.

You can try it [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4189b754-c297-52f5-ac81-63180293a5bf)

Edit :
I just see @Peter's comment, you definitively should read the question he linked, it will help you understand the whole thing.