# How can I make my website’s profile URL’s more user friendly

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, user-interface, url

Currently I have it set up so that the user profile is viewed at:  `mywebsite.com/profile.php?user=username`
I need that to somehow redirect to something like `mywebsite.com/username` and the profile page still work. Any help would be nice.

Comment: This question is pretty broad, and I'm 100% sure has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)