# Optimize Long URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have theses URLs

```
http://www.website.com/?goto=plaforms
http://www.website.com/?goto=offers&platform=dates
http://www.website.com/?goto=profile&member=1
http://www.website.com/?goto=product&offer=2
```

I want to change them using .htaccess to be like this:

```
http://www.website.com/plaforms
http://www.website.com/offers/dates
http://www.website.com/profile/1
http://www.website.com/product/2
```

I've tried this but not working

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?goto=$1
```

Honestly  I have no clue how to do it.

**UPDATE:**
I have an index.php in which I call all pages

index.php

```
$page = $_GET['goto'];
$url  = $page.'.php';

if(file_exists($url)):  
  include($url);
else:
  header('location:'?goto=home');
endif;
```

The 1st param **?goto=**  calls for pages and the second param call data from database

Comment: I believe your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your question. Could you please do let us know what is the logic of having different different query string values like `&member` and `&offer` for better understanding of the question.

Comment: The problem description "not working" isn't working.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated my question. hopefully will help for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write rewrite rules like these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#The rules
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)?$ /?goto=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^offers\/dates$ /?goto=offers&platform=dates [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile\/(\d+)$ /?goto=profile&member=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product\/(\d+)$ /?goto=product&offer=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is some of the parameter values can not be derived from your fancy URLs. Therefore, you have to spell them out fully (like /offers/dates) or partially like /profile/x and /product/x). The only really generic rule is the first one that rewrites anything /xxx to goto=xxx. So, depending on y our URL space you may have to write a lot of rules.